# Family of groups with specific presentation

Tags: group-theory, terminology, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

Is there a name for the family of groups given by $n$ generators ($g_1, g_2,\ldots g_n$) and the following relations?

$$g_ig_jg_i = g_jg_ig_j,~\forall i,j \in \lbrace 1,\ldots n\rbrace,~i\neq j\\
g_ig_i = 1,\forall i \in \lbrace 1,\ldots n \rbrace
$$

The relations are quite similar to the ones for a braid group, but then the first relation holds between *any* pair of generators and the generators are self-inverse.

Is there a name for this family of groups?

Comment: You can rewrite this to be the Coxeter group corresponding to the complete Coxeter graph. This will be infinite except in the small trivial cases. I don't think I have seen any special name for it, though someone else might have.